# How can i make the rest of the mouse smooth, without having the imperfections that the buttons have?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image][image][image][image: enter imageenter image description here description here]

If I try to extrude from the buttons the surface will have the same imperfections. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, specifically a couple pictures of the imperfections you are talking about. This will better allow people to identify your problem.

Comment: @Cultmethod Alredy added more pictures to the post, thanks. The left and right mouse buttons have these "imperfections", unequal parts on the surface as shown in the 4th pic. But if I try to extrude, the rest of the mouse will have the same imperfections (1st pic), and i want it to be a smooth surface

Comment: what you want is hard to understand, could you try to reformulate please?